# IF statement in Powershell ISE

Tags: powershell, if-statement, user-input

I need help having my input correctly returned:

- When the user hits "1" it should say "Hello, Person!".
- When the user hits "2" it should say "Goodbye Person!".

I can only get the second option to come up.

```
$title = "Convert Bat to Ps1"
$message = "Press 1 to say Hello, or Press 2 to say Goodbye"
$option1 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "1", "1"
$option2 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "2", "2"
$options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($option1, $option2)
$choice=$host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 1)
If ($option1 -eq 1) {
  'Hello, Person!'
  exit
  } 
If ($option2 -ne 2) {
  'Goodbye, Person!'
  exit
}
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the code [into your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69543240/edit) _as text_ - ain't nobody got time for transcribing code from a screenshot :)

Comment: `$option1` isn't 1. It's a `ChoiceDescription`. You're asking it if something that is an instance of a class called `ChoiceDescription` is 1 or 2. It's neither. It's a `ChoiceDescription`. Look at the *properties* of the object.

Comment: in addition to what Daniel Mann pointed out, your `if` would work better with `if/elseif` instead of two `if` blocks. heck, since there are only a few possible values, you may be able to use a simple `if/else`.

Comment: @DanielMann I have done some research to figure out what to use instead of ChoiceDescription, but I am having no luck. Is there a different command I should be using?

Answer (score 1):

The outcome of the prompt choice will be stored in `$choice`, not in `$Option1` or `$Option2`.

The value returned from `PromptForChoice` will be zero-indexed, so to test for option 1:

```
if($choice -eq 0){
  "Option 1 was chosen"
}

if($choice -eq 1){
  "Option 2 was chosen"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not check on variable `$option1` or `$option2`, but instead test the value of variable `$choice`, because that tells you whhich button was clicked.

Also, below I use a `switch` instead of multiple `if\else`:

```
$title   = "Convert Bat to Ps1"
$message = "Press 1 to say Hello, or Press 2 to say Goodbye"
$option1 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "1", "Option 1"
$option2 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "2", "Option 2"
$options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($option1, $option2)
$choice  = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 1)

# $choice is now an Int32 value, it's the Index of the button that is clicked:
# 0 for option 1 and 1 for option 2

switch ($choice) {
    0 { 'Hello, Person!' }  # left out the exit here so you can stay in your PowerShell instance
    1 { 'Goodbye, Person!'; exit }
}
```